# npm ERR! missing script: start Vue.js Error

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, npm-scripts, npm-start

When I install Vuetable. ( `npm install vuetable-2@next --save` ) I get the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! missing script: start
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     x\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-23T08_51_20_971Z-debug.log
> PS x\Desktop\dd\frontend> npm start serve
> npm ERR! missing script: start
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     x\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-23T08_52_32_164Z-debug.log
> ```

I tried to remove the `node_modules` folder and install it again. Also I tried, `npm clean cache --force` but still get the same error. How can I fix it?

This is my package.json file :

```json
{
  "name": "architectui-vue-pro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^11.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.1",
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.6.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "countup.js": "^1.9.3",
    "css-file-icons": "0.0.7",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.6",
    "leaflet": "^1.4.0",
    "linearicons": "^1.0.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.5",
    "mockjs": "^1.0.1-beta3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "pdfjs": "^2.3.8",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "v-mask": "^1.3.3",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-clipboards": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-color": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-country-flag": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-countup-v2": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-element-loading": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-fancybox": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-full-calendar": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-ladda": "0.0.15",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-pdf": "^4.0.8",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-rate": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-select": "^2.6.4",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-sidebar-menu": "^3.7.0",
    "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.8.16",
    "vue-sparklines": "^0.1.9",
    "vue-spinkit": "^1.7.12",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-sticky-directive": "0.0.8",
    "vue-tabs-with-active-line": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-textarea-autosize": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-toastr": "^2.0.16",
    "vue2-animate": "^2.1.0",
    "vue2-circle-progress": "^1.2.3",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^2.11.0",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.8",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.6",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^1.2.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetable-2": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5",
    "vuetrend": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the start script. Add this to your `package.json`

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "vue-cli-service start",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```